# How can I prove that an operator is well defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following operator:

$\langle Au, v\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)|^{p-2}u(x)v(x)dx$ where $u,v\in W^{\sigma, p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$

and want to show that it is well defined.

We have some examples in my script. One time they show that for an operator B applies $|\langle Bu,v\rangle| \leq c|u|^2|v|$, where c is some constant. The other time they show that $|\langle Bu,v\rangle|< \infty$. I don't get why this shows in this two cases that the operator is well defined.

Maybe someone can explain that for me and tell me what I have to show in my case.

---

Edit:

$V^* = \{f:V\to\mathbb{R} |$ f linear, bounded, continuous$\}$

So we want to show that for each $u\in V$ Au is linear, bounded and continuous.

As $\langle Au, v\rangle$ is an integral it is linear and continous (right)?

So we just have to show that Au is bounded?

Comment: "So we just have to show that $Au$ is bounded?" Yes, that's the point.  "As ⟨Au,v⟩ is an integral it is linear and continuous" Almost. You want to show that the integral converges before talking about its linearity and the continuity of a linear functional is the same as its boundedness.

Comment: thanks a lot @fedja. In my specific case I can write $|\langle Au, v\rangle| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)^{p-1} v(x)|dx$. I thought about using Hölder then. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |u(x)^{p-1} v(x)|dx <= ||u^{p-1}||_{L^p}||v||_{L^q} = ||u||^{p-1}_{L^p}||v||_{L^q}$ where $q\geq 1$ s.t. $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1.$ As u is in $L^p$ we have $||u||^{p-1}_{L^p} < \infty$. What about $||v||_{L_q}$?

Comment: Holder is the right idea but $\|u^{p-1}\|_{L^p}$ is generally not $\|u\|_{L^p}^{p-1}$. You want to choose some other exponent to get this identity. Hint: you want to end up with $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$ on *both* $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I could choose 2 as exponent then I would have the same norm vor u and v but not $L^p$

Comment: Ok, if I choose p/p-1 as one exponent and the other one as p-1, I get:
$\int |u^{p-1}v| \leq (\int |u^{p-1}|^{p/p-1})^{\frac{p-1}{p}} ||v||_{L^{p-1}} = (\int |u|^{p})^{frac{p-1}{p}} ||v||_{L^{p-1}} = ||u||_{L^p}^{p-1}||v||_{L^{p-1}}$

Comment: The first one is fine. But what do you need the other one to be for Holder to work?

Comment: ups, you're right. the other exponent should be p, not (p-1).

Comment: So all together
$\int |u^{p-1}v| \leq (\int |u^{p-1}|^{p/p-1})^{\frac{p-1}{p}} ||v||_{L^p} = (\int |u|^{p})^{\frac{p-1}{p}} ||v||_{L^p} = ||u||_{L^p}^{p-1}||v||_{L^p} $
As $u,v \in L^p$ it holds $\langle Au, v \rangle \leq ||u||_{L^p}^{p-1}||v||_{L^p} < \infty$

Comment: Yep. Note that you also got the boundedness of the linear functional $v\mapsto\langle Au,v\rangle$. I guess you can figure out the rest yourself :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help!